# Class Library(.Net Core)" not available on visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2015 when adding a new project you would get a "Class Library(.Net Core)"

This option seems to be no longer available in VS 2017.

How do I get "Class Library(.Net Standard)"?

Comment: Check out https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/16/announcing-net-core-rc2/ - in particular the section titled: .NET Standard Library

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you have to do is go start the *Visual Studio Installer* and select the "Modify" at your installation of VS 2017.

Then check the box at ".NET Core and Docker (Preview)". This will later be replaced by ".NET Core and Docker" once it's out of preview.

You can see the instructions here: [VS Dotnet Core Page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2017)

> Install the .NET Core tools preview workload
>
> Make sure you installed the workload ".NET Core and Docker (Preview)". You can check and install workloads by launching the Visual Studio Installer.